# Finding the transitive closure given a digraph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I want to find the transitive closure, $R^\infty$, of the relations represented by the digraphs below:

[image]

For the first digraph I have the relation $R_1=\{(a, b), (b, c), (c, d)\}$, and for the second I have $R_2=\{(a, b), (a, c), (a, d), (a,e)\}$.

Would I be correct to say the transitive closure of $R_1$ is $\{(a, b), (a, c), (a, d), (b,c), (b, d), (c, d)\}$? I'm not sure where to start with the second, digraph, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the transitive closure of a relation $R$ is the set of all $(x,y)$ so that, for some $n$ there are $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ so that $(x,z_1) \in R$, $(z_n,y) \in R$, and for each $k$ we have $(z_k, z_{k+1}) \in R$.

Graphically, let's add a vertex for each element of our set. Then, for each $(x,y) \in R$ we add a directed edge from $x$ to $y$. You've already done this in your examples.

Then the transitive closure is given by the digraph where we connect $x$ and $y$ if and only if they were connected by a (directed) *path* in our original graph.

Then for your first graph, we should have an edge for each path. So (as you've correctly computed) we need to add in edges $(a,c)$, $(a,d)$, and $(b,d)$.

For your second graph, we do the same thing. But notice that now there *are no paths* of length $> 1$. So the transitive closure is just the same relation we started with. We can also compute this from the relation directly. After all, there are no points $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ in $R$, so we have no new relations to add.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just have one question, why does it matter the length of a path?

Comment: Happy to help ^_^. The length of the path matters because a path of length $1$ is just an edge in your graph, so we aren't adding anything new. But a path of length $2$ (or more) is something that we might need to add to the transitive closure that wasn't in the graph we started with